# Is it possible to prevent creation of epub and pdf versions of book with bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown

I've started to play with bookdown (RStudio, Mac) to write some lecture notes, that I will change a lot during the course. Just for keeping things tidy, I would prefer not to create epub or pdf versions of the notes, or, alternatively, hide the download icon. Is this possible? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to prevent that epub and pdf versions are produced (assuming that you're working in a bookdown RStudio project) is to check `bookdown::gitbook` in the build pane an then hit *Build Book*.

[image]

You may also hide the download button by setting `download: no` in the *_output.yml* file:

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    download: no
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Changing the `_output.yml` file did exactly what I wanted.