# Strange error with italic capital Greek letters

Tags: r, bookdown

I am using R and Bookdown. In maths expressions, italic capital Greek letters cause a warning which I don't quite understand. For example, the input

```
some text $\varGamma$ some text
```

gives

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '\varGamma', rendering as TeX:
  \varGamma
           ^
  unexpected eof
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

Yet I *do* see an italic capital Gamma in the html output.

Since Bookdown also produces pdf and epub outputs, I tried disabling those by putting `download: no` in the `_output.yml` file, as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64738688/6090141), in case the error comes from compiling one of them:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
[...]
download: no
```

but the warning persists.

Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the culprit, which in my case probably comes from my using the script `_build.sh` provided by Bookdown to compile the input (I believe Rstudio users don't need it).

Removing the line for compilation of the **epub** output from `_build.sh`:

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::epub_book')"
```

as well as disabling the epub output by removing `, "epub"` in `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
[...]
    download: ["pdf"]
```

made the warning disappear.